# How to pass a URL as a parameter to a Spring 3.1 controller

Tags: ajax, spring, url, parameters, controller

This is fairly straightforward.  I need to pass a url to my controller from my front end through an AJAX call, ie "http://www.x.com/some/path".  Spring controllers interpret portions of the path as variables, with "/" delineating, so this obviously doesn't work:  "http://myserver.com/myapp/controller/http://www.x.com/some/path".

So my question is, how can I get that value to my controller?

Edit: I'm using Dojo 1.8 on my front end.

Comment: Are you passing it as a parameter? The controller doesn't try to interpret parameters.

Comment: No, that's my dilemma.  The Spring way of doing it would be  "http://myserver.com/myapp/controller/http://www.x.com/some/path" but that obviously won't work.

Comment: If you want to pass a URL as a parameter, you would use "myserver.com/myapp/controller?urlParam=http://www.x.com/some/path/" Spring passes the value of urlParam to your controller. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding the variable for the url in your JavaScript.

```
var url = encodeURIComponent("http://www.x.com/some/path");
// http%3A%2F%2Fwww.x.com%2Fsome%2Fpath
```

Then you can retrieve the original value by decoding it in Java:

```
URLDecoder.decode("http%3A%2F%2Fwww.x.com%2Fsome%2Fpath", "UTF-8")
// http://www.x.com/some/path
```

Comment: Haven't tested this yet but I'm going to go ahead and accept it as it seems like the logical thing to do... thanks :)

Comment: FYI this still doesn't work. Consensus on the internet states you should Base64 encode the URL values when passing them in the URL, which turned out to be a pain. Initially I just did a string replace on the "/" to make them [fs], which was also ugly. Ultimately I changed the method from GET to POST and I could pass the URLs in the request without doing anything to them.